# Stripe integration with Django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am following a tutorial on stripe.com, to accept a charge it says to use the following form and capture the `Token` it returns in a view

Stripe "Checkout" form:

```
<form action="{% url 'payment' %}" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_z1bxF7Bk4Rk9PZuBFHMrYZnj"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="Example charge"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

The next step says to simply copy and paste this and your test account should be able to accept charges
Stripe view:

```
def payment(request):
    # Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
    # See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
    stripe.api_key = "sk_test_BJUliYkgS5VZEKFM1UQAz9cF"

    # Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
    # Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
    token = request.POST['stripeToken']

    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
        amount=999,
        currency='usd',
        description='Example charge',
        source=token,
    )
```

but `stripeToken` is mentioned nowhere in the form and the code returns an error because of this, can someone explain where this is coming from? (Note, the example was in Flask so I changed   `token = request.form['stripeToken'] # Using Flask` to `token = request.POST['stripeToken'] #using Django`

Both of these can be found at https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart (Step 1 shows 'Checkout', step 2 shows the python code) Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have a charge model?  Can you include.

Comment: Or have you include the stripe library?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
token = request.GET.get['stripeToken']
```

Comment: this returns `File ".../views.py", line 155, in payment
    token = request.POST.get['stripeToken']
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.